# Why can I not run lsb_release without -a parameter on ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Why can I not run lsb_release without -a parameter on ubuntu? Because When I run lsb_release command, I am taking message "No LSB modules are available".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-lsb_release/) for `lsb_release`:

```
   If no options are given, the -v option is assumed.
```

The -v option:

```
   -v, --version
          Show the version of the LSB against which your current installa‐
          tion  is  compliant.   The version is expressed as a colon sepa‐
          rated list of LSB module descriptions.
```

If you don't have any lsb modules installed you'll get the message you describe. The `-a` switch shows all information available.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:** `lsb_release` command - **prints you the linux distribution version on machine.**

**Solution**: `-v` (version) is in default when no parameters are in. For watching linux distribution full information always use the `-a` flag or `-r` for release number.

**examples**:

```
$lsb_release -a

#output:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$lsb_release -r

#output:
Release:    18.04
```

**Flags** are:

```
       -v, --version
              Show the version of the LSB against which your current installation is compliant.  The version is expressed as a colon separated list of LSB module descriptions.

       -i, --id
              Display the distributor's ID.

       -d, --description
              Display a description of the currently installed distribution.

       -r, --release
              Display the release number of the currently installed distribution.

       -c, --codename
              Display the code name of the currently installed distribution.

       -a, --all
              Display all of the above information.

       -s, --short
              Use the short output format for any information displayed.  This format omits the leading header(s).

       -h, --help
              Show summary of options.
```